# Export import of asian languages data in sql server

Tags: sql-server, collation, bcp

I am using BCP to import and export data, but some of it is in an asian language (think chinese or korean). It is stored correctly in the SQL, at least that's what I see from SSMS, though the collation is Latin1. However, when using BCP the export doesn't output the data in the right language anymore.

I used the options -w and -N but neither worked.

Comment: when you use the -N flag the data is exported in Native format which is basically binary data. How do you know that the output data is not in the right format? The only way to know is to import into another table.